# What are the exact axioms to uniquely define the Minkowski metric tensor as a bilinear map?

Tags: general-relativity, special-relativity, differential-geometry, metric-tensor

I have read that the definition of a metric tensor is a map with the following axioms:

- a bilinear form from the tangent vector space (of a smooth manifold) to the real field
- symmetric
- nondegenerate

[**Question**] Now, from a purely mathematical prospective: given a map X (defined on a 4D tangent space), is it enough to say that:

- $X$ is a metric tensor
- $X$ has signature $(-, +, +, +)$ or $(+, -, -, -)$

to deduce that X is the Minkowski metric tensor?

*Note: if the answer is yes, it would mean that Minkowski is the only metric tensor that as a bilinear form has the signature $(-, +, +, +)$.*

I think that these axioms are not enough, because in GR we work with metric tensors with the same signature (see [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/694473)). Therefore:

[**Subquestion part a**] Which additional axioms should we include to uniquely define the Minkowski metric tensor as a map?

[**Subquestion part b**] Would the additional axiom simply be explicitly stating that the coefficients of the bilinear form are all 1 (so -1,+1,+1,+1)?

Comment: Are you allowing similarity transformations in your definition of what the Minkowski metric "is"?  Any bilinear form whose components (in a given basis) are $$\begin{bmatrix}-a^2 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & b^2 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & c^2 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & d^2 \end{bmatrix}$$has signature $(-,+,+,+)$.  But it's only equal to the Minkowski metric (in this basis) if $a = b = c = d = 1$.

Comment: Or, for another example, consider the bilinear form with components$$\begin{bmatrix} -a^2 + c^2 & -ab + cd & 0 & 0 \\ -ab+cd & -b^2 + d^2 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$$ which is what you get when you apply an arbitrary similarity transformation on the $t$ and $x$ coordinates of the Minkowski metric.  Is this still the Minkowski metric by your definition?

Comment: The Minkowski spacetime in is a four-dimensional affine space whose vector space of translations is equipped with a non-singular bilinear form with signature -,-,-,+.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert Hi! In my question, I am not defining Minkowski metric because that would be circular reasoning from my side: i am asking readers to define what *it is*, via telling me what are its axioms. The idea is to pretend that i don't even know what Minkowski metric is, and that readers tell me what it is, by defining the axioms that **uniquely** characterise the map. (Are the axioms that i wrote enough to do so, or are more needed? If so, which ones?)

Comment: @ValterMoretti Hi! I am asking the axioms of the bilinear form, not of the spacetime. I can however deduce from your definition, that for you the answer to my question is **yes**, and therefore according to you, the Minkowski metric tensor is the only metric tensor that as a bilinear form has the signature (-, +, +, +).

Comment: Actually not, you can have different metric tensor with the same signature on a given vector space. So you have different structures of Minkowski spacetime on the same four dimensional affine space.

Comment: @ValterMoretti in this case could you please answer the question i posted, which was about what **uniquely** defines the **map** of the Minkowski metric tensor? (possibly in an axiomatic way, as i did in the question)

Comment: I guess my question boils down to "What do you mean by *define*?"  If you want a unique definition of a bilinear form, you have to have a notion of when two bilinear forms are "the same" and when they are "different".  So are two bilinear forms "the same", according to you, if one can be obtained from the other by a similarity transformation on the underlying space?  You'll get different definitions depending on the answer to this question.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert about your question to define "define" i leave it to the readers; I personally don't know what physicists (and/or mathematicians) commonly do when they uniquely define a bilinear form

Comment: @TrentKent6 to uniquely define a Lorentzian scalar form it is necessary and sufficient to single out a basis (as an ordered set of vectors) of the space of translations and declare that the scalar product assumes there the matrix representation $diag(-1,+1,+1,+1)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a non-degenerate, symmetric, bi-linear form over the tangent space, expressed as $g_{μν} = g(∂_μ, ∂_ν)$, or equivalently as the tensor $g = g_{μν} dx^μ ⊗ dx^ν$ (summation convention used), where $\{x^μ: μ = 0, 1, ..., N\}$ are the coordinates (at least, locally) and $∂_μ = ∂/∂x^μ$ are the partial differential operators comprising the tangent frame, impose the following extra conditions expressed in terms of the Lie derivatives $ℒ_X$ of certain vector fields $X$:

(1) Homogeneity: $ℒ_{∂_ρ} g = 0$, for all $ρ = 0, 1, ..., N$,

(2) N+1-Isotropy: $ℒ_{x_σ ∂_ρ - x_ρ ∂_σ} g = 0$, for all $ρ, σ = 0, 1, ..., N$ (without loss of generality, you can take $ρ ≠ σ$ or even $ρ < σ$); where $x_0 = x^0$ and $x_i = -x^i$, for $i = 1, 2, ..., N$. That gives you bona fide spatial *isotropy* with respect to the space-like dimensions $1, 2, ..., N$ and *non-accelerationosity* (for lack of a better term) with respect to the mixed combinations of the time-like dimension $0$ with each of the spatial dimensions.

Then, the metric is a Minkowski metric (up to a non-zero constant multiple), if $N > 1$.

(The Minkowski metric $η = η_{ρσ} dx^ρ ⊗ dx^σ$ is sneaked into the conditions as the constant diagonal matrix $(+1,-1,-1,-1)$ of coefficients in $x_ρ = η_{ρσ} x^σ$. There is no escaping The $η$.)

For $N = 3$ and 3+1 dimensions, the 10 Lie vectors, in 3D vector notation are:
$${∂ \over ∂t},$$
$$∇ = \left({∂ \over ∂x}, {∂ \over ∂y}, {∂ \over ∂z}\right),$$
$$×∇ = \left(y {∂ \over ∂z} - z {∂ \over ∂y}, z {∂ \over ∂x} - x {∂ \over ∂z}, x {∂ \over ∂y} - y {∂ \over ∂x}\right),$$
$$t∇ +  {∂ \over ∂t} = \left(t {∂ \over ∂x} + x {∂ \over ∂t}, t {∂ \over ∂y} + y {∂ \over ∂t}, t {∂ \over ∂z} + z {∂ \over ∂t}\right),$$
where $t = x^0$ and $ = \left(x, y, z\right) = \left(x^1, x^2, x^3\right)$. The four sets of Lie vectors are, respectively, for *Stationarity*, *Spatial Homogeneity*, *Spatial Isotropy* and *Non-Accelerationosity*. The metric is to be stationary, spatially homongeneous, isotropic and *non-accelerating* (for lack of a better term).

First, we do (1). Since
$$ℒ_{∂_ρ} dx^μ = ∂_ρ ˩ ddx^μ + d(∂_ρ ˩ dx^μ) = ∂_μ ˩ 0 + d(δ_ρ^μ) = 0,$$
and $ℒ_{∂_ρ} g_{μν} = ∂_ρ g_{μν}$, then using the product rule for $ℒ_{∂_ρ}$, we have:
$$0 = ℒ_{∂_ρ} g_{μν} dx^μ ⊗ dx^ν = \left(∂_ρ g_{μν}\right) dx^μ ⊗ dx^ν + g_{μν} (0) ⊗ dx^ν + dx^μ ⊗ (0) = ∂_ρ g_{μν} dx^μ ⊗ dx^ν,$$
from which it follows that $∂_ρ g_{μν} = 0$ or that the components $g_{μν}$ are all constant.

Second, we do (2). In general
$$ℒ_X dx^μ = X ˩ ddx^μ + d(X ˩ dx^μ) = ∂_μ ˩ 0 + dX^μ = dX^μ,$$
so for $X = x_σ ∂_ρ - x_ρ ∂_σ$, we have $X^μ = x_σ δ_ρ^μ - x_ρ δ_σ^μ$ and, thus:
$$ℒ_{x_σ ∂_ρ - x_ρ ∂_σ} dx^μ = d\left(x_σ δ_ρ^μ - x_ρ δ_σ^μ\right) = δ_ρ^μ dx_σ - δ_σ^μ dx_ρ.$$
Also, since the components $g_{μν}$ are constant, then we have $ℒ_X g_{μν} = X^ρ ∂_ρ g_{μν} = 0$, regardless of what $X$ is. Thus, using the product rule, again, we have:
$$0 = ℒ_{x_σ ∂_ρ - x_ρ ∂_σ} g = (0) dx^μ ⊗ dx^ν + g_{μν} \left(δ_ρ^μ dx_σ - δ_σ^μ dx_ρ\right) ⊗ dx^ν + g_{μν} dx^μ ⊗ \left(δ_ρ^ν dx_σ - δ_σ^ν dx_ρ\right),$$
or
$$0 = g_{ρν} dx_σ ⊗ dx^ν - g_{σν} dx_ρ ⊗ dx^ν + g_{μρ} dx^μ ⊗ dx_σ - g_{μσ} dx^μ ⊗ dx_ρ,$$
or, componentwise, using the symmetry of $η$ and (assumed) symmtry of $g$ to swap indices:
$$0 = g_{νρ} η_{μσ} - g_{νσ} η_{μρ} + g_{μρ} η_{νσ} - g_{μσ} η_{νρ}.$$

This condition is trivial if $ρ = σ$ or $μ = ν$; particularly, if $N = 0$. If $N = 1$, then without loss of generality, we could take $(ρ,σ) = (0,1) = (μ,ν)$ and write
$$0 = g_{10} (0) - g_{11} (-1) + g_{00} (+1) - g_{01} (0) = g_{00} + g_{11}.$$
That's the best you can do. The metric forms a constant symmetric trace-free $2×2$ matrix.

If $N > 1$, choose any $μ$, $ρ ≠ μ$ and $σ = ν ≠ μ, ρ$. Then, we have:
$$0 = g_{νρ} (0) - g_{νσ} (0) + g_{μρ} η_{νσ} - g_{μσ} (0) = ±g_{μρ}.$$
Thus, $g_{μρ} ≠ 0$ for $ρ ≠ μ$ and $g$ forms a diagonal matrix. Next, choose any $ρ = μ$ and $σ = ν ≠ μ, ρ$. Then, we have:
$$0 = g_{νρ} (0) - g_{νσ} η_{μρ} + g_{μρ} η_{νσ} - g_{μσ} (0) = -g_{νσ} η_{μρ} + g_{μρ} η_{νσ}.$$
From this, it follows that $g_{μρ}/η_{μp} = g_{νσ}/η_{νσ}$. Therefore, $g$ is a constant multiple of the Minkowski metric $η$. Since $g$ is assumed to be non-degenerate, the constant multiple must be non-zero. Otherwise, if it's degenerate, the constant multiple is 0, and then $g$ must be 0 and totally degenerate.

Comment: 1) do you have sources? i would TRULY like to read more about this exact answer.

Comment: 2) do these axioms also work for the "minkowski metric tensor" which appears ONLY LOCALLY in any possible general relativity geometries?

Comment: That's actually the standard way to get solutions possessing a range of symmetries. Start with a general metric, require that its Lie bracket with the relevant symmetries vanish. That defines the _isometries_ of the metric and the vector fields are called its _Killing Fields_. For the black hole (or Schwarzschild) solution, for instance, you impose only the isotropy and stationary conditions, not spatial homogeneity (since it has a center) nor non-accelerationess (since the center is fixed). The construction is not local; particularly, the homogeneity (i.e. "translation") symmetries are not.

Comment: Adding to my previous reply, in the "Exact Solutions" book/catalogue, they actually do the analyses, in a similar way, with Killing Fields to lay out the general solutions families, before going into the catalogue entries. https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/exact-solutions-of-einsteins-field-equations/11CF6CFCC10CC62B9B299F08C32C37A6

Answer (score 6):

*Up to isomorphisms*,  the **Minkowski spacetime** is a real  four-dimensional  affine space $M^4$ equipped with a Lorentzian scalar product $g$ in the vector space $V^4$ of translations of the affine space.

If $V$ is a real four-dimensional vector space,  a Lorentzian scalar product is a symmetric bilinear map $g: V\times V\to \mathbb{R}$ whose Sylvester's canonical form is $\text{diag}(-1,+1,+1,+1)$.

Given a real four-dimensional vector space $V$ and  a vector basis $e_1,e_2,e_3,e_4$, there exists a unique Lorentzian scalar product whose matrix representation on that basis is $\text{diag}(-1,+1,+1,+1)$.

Therefore, to uniquely fix a Lorentzian scalar product it is sufficient to single out a basis and to declare that the scalar product has the canonical form in that basis.

On the other hand if you have a Lorentzian scalar product, there are infinitely many bases as above. These special bases are related to each other through the transformations of the Lorentz group. (That is the definition of the Lorentz group.)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134105/discussion-on-answer-by-valter-moretti-what-are-the-exact-axioms-to-uniquely-def).

Comment: what is the difference between saying that the scalar product has diag(−1,+1,+1,+1) as Sylvester's canonical form (as you do in your answer) and saying that the coefficients of the bilinear form are (-1,+1,+1,+1) (as I do at the end of my question)?

Answer (score 3):

Let $p$ be a point in the manifold. By means of coordinate transformations, any Lorentzian metric tensor can be put in the form $\text{diag}(-+++)$ at $p$ by definition. Hence, your axioms are not enough to define the Minkowski metric.

Referring to the components of the tensor won't work, since they change a lot between different coordinate systems. For example, in spherical coordinates, the same Minkowski metric can be written as $\text{diag}(-1, 1, r^2, r^2 \sin^2\theta)$. Instead, we need to provide some definition that is coordinate invariant, so that it holds regardless of the particular coordinate system we choose to work with.

A property that only the Minkowski metric satisfies is that it is the flat metric, i.e., the [Riemann tensor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_curvature_tensor) associated with its [Levi-Civita connection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levi-Civita_connection) vanishes. This property, if added to the ones you mentioned, characterizes the Minkowski metric uniquely.

In short, the Minkowski metric is the only flat Lorentzian metric. Notice that this is not enough to characterize the whole manifold as Minkowski spacetime: Minkowski spacetime is topologically $\mathbb{R}^4$, but one can have a flat spacetime with a four-torus topology, for example (namely, space looks like Pacman's world, in which you go out on one end and come back through the other side, and the same holds for time).

Comment: i've a question. In the case of the real 4D affine space of special relativity, we know that Lorentz transformations (+ translations) are the unique transforms that leave invariant the line element of the manifold. If my coordinate system is always spherical (so starts&ends spherical) the inner product of the manifold (i.e. minkowski metric tensor, which can give the line element) should be written accordingly (as displayed in this answer). My question is then: how would the Lorentz transformation look like, in order to leave this inner product (and consequently, the line element) invariant?

Comment: @TrentKent6 I think that is complicated enough to deserve a new question hahaha. Not all of the Lorentz transformations would keep that line element invariant: if you make a boost in some direction, you're choosing a direction in which you're boosting, so the previously isotropic coordinate system will have to adapt to deal with that. My >guess< is that only rotations of the coordinate system would satisfy this, but I'm not entirely sure

Comment: I was thinking back at your answer, and there's something unclear in your definition of minkowski ≡ metric tensor with (R=0). Consider a completely flat spacetime (so R=0 everywhere) and a non-inertial (aka accelerating) observer. GLOBALLY (for example, at a point located 1 km away; so i stress: *not locally*!) this observer will see the line element there be described not by the minkowski metric, but by a different metric (since he's not inertial). And yet, it's still R=0 there. If they could describe the global point with minkowski, they would be inertial, contradicting the starting point...

Comment: [...] it follows that, since the metric tensor used for the far away point is not minkowski and since it has R=0, minkowski can't be the only metric tensor with (R=0).

Comment: @TrentKent6 The tensor is coordinate and observer independent. An accelerated observer does not see a Minkowski metric in the same sense that spherical coordinates do not write $(-,+,+,+)$. The tensor is a geometric object defined without the need of coordinates or observers, only its components depend on the coordinates

Comment: Also, notice I said the Riemann tensor vanishes, $R_{abc}{}^{d} = 0$. There are metrics that have vanishing Ricci scalar $R=g^{ab}R_{acb}{}^{c} =0$ but are not the Minkowski metric.

Comment: Sloppy notation, by "R" I was meaning Riemann tensor, not Ricci scalar

Comment: But then, if minkowski ≡ metric tensor with (Riemann tensor=0), what about local inertial frames? there the metric can always be put to minkowski, but Riemann tensor is not necessarily 0... the definition does not seem to hold there...

Comment: @TrentKent6 Just having $\text{d}s^2 = - \text{d}t^2 + \text{d}x^2 + \text{d}y^2 + \text{d}z^2$ in some coordinate system is not enough to say this is the Minkowski metric. All metrics can be put in this form in a suitable coordinate system. This form is not the Minkowski metric. A metric is not just the expression in coordinates, it is a linear map defined on each point of the manifold. If you choose a local inertial frame, the metric will assume other values in other points which are not just $(-+++)$, because it is still a function

Comment: The metric is an object that is not dependent on the choice of frame. It is often expressed in a frame for convenience, but it is defined without the need for an specific frame. What really singles out the Minkowski metric is that it is flat, and this is a statement that does not depend on coordinates. Choosing a local inertial frame is choosing a coordinate system, choosing the metric to be flat isn't. The Minkowski metric is flat, all other metrics can also be written as $(-+++)$

Comment: i know, the point is that locally the metric can *always* be put minkowski, but nevertheless the *Riemann tensor does not have to be 0 there*, because the metric could be anything different in the neighbouring points; therefore minkowski metric can't be set ≡ to metric tensor with (Riemann tensor=0)

Comment: @TrentKent6 the metric is not defined a point at a time to be put to be Minkowski. *In a single point*, you can write the metric *with the same components* that the Minkowski metric has in a particular coordinate system. That doesn't mean the metric can be put to be Minkowski. It is still not the Minkowski metric because the metric depends on the neighboring points as well.

Comment: It is similar to saying that just because the function $x^2$ vanishes at zero, it must be the zero function. You can't just look one point at a time and completely ignore the other ones. The metric changes from point to point and, in general, you'll only be able to write it in locally inertial coordinates one point at a time, precisely because the metric is not in general the Minkowski metric and hence it has curvature

Comment: You are correct in saying that one can always choose a coordinate system in which the metric is written as $\text{d}s^2 = -\text{d}t^2 + \text{d}x^2 + \text{d}y^2 + \text{d}z^2$ *at some point* even though the Riemann tensor is not zero. You are mistaken in identifying the expression $\text{d}s^2 = -\text{d}t^2 + \text{d}x^2 + \text{d}y^2 + \text{d}z^2$ with the Minkowski metric without the extra impositions that this expression should hold throughout the entire manifold, which would then mean the Riemann curvature vanishes.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's enough.

To be pedantic, though, a metric always has a positive definite signature, aka (+,+,+, ..,+) whilst a semi-metric can have arbitrary signature. A manifold with a metric is called a Riemannian manifold whilst a manifold with a semi-metric is called a semi-Riemannian manifold. Often the qualifier 'pseudo' is used instead of 'semi', but I prefer to not use that as the conventional understanding of pseudo means false or fake. A Lorentzian manifold is semi-Riemannian manifold with signature (-+++...+) or (+----...-) and this is what you are after. Minkowski space is simply a flat 4d Lorentzian manifold.

Comment: hi, to which part of my question is your answer "yes" referring to? is it the "question" or the "subquestion part b" (where i introduce the coefficients -1,1,1,1)?

Comment: @TrentKent6: To the main question.

Comment: but the Schwarzschild metric tensor also satisfies those 2 axioms, and yet it is not the Minkowski metric tensor...

Comment: @TrentKent6: Ah, ok. I see what you are driving at. I'd say that the additional axiom you need is that the space is flat, that is the Riemann curvature vanishes.

Comment: but in curved spacetime, locally (at any point) you still have minkowski metric tensor, and yet at at that point the Riemann curvature is not required to vanish...

Comment: @TrentKent6: Sure, that Minkowski metric is on the tangent plane of the manifold at that point. We require this by definition of the metric tensor field - it's a field of metrics. When the curvature vanishes then you have parallel transport and you can transport the Minkowski structure in a parallel way across the whole manifold and this is means it is isomorphic to a Minkowski space.

Comment: @TrentKent6: ... actually, it doesn't. There are still some additional problems with my characterisation. For example, the curvature of the ordinary cylinder and a plane also vanish but they are not globally isomorphic, only locally. It looks like you will also need some topolpgical restrictions, for example, saying the space os contractible which is equivalent to saying that its fundamental group should vanish (ie be trivial).

Comment: the point is that Riemann=0 can't be the additional axiom to uniquely define η, because there are instances where η is present, but Riemann≠0, such as *locally* at any point of a curved spacetime

Comment: @TrentKent6: Sure, I agreed above. You need global topological constraints like the space is contractible.