# Do all metric tensors have signature (1,3) or (3,1) in the spacetime of General Relativity?

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry

Do all metric tensors have signature (-,+,+,+) or (+,-,-,-) in the Pseudo-riemannian manifold describing spacetime in the Theory of General Relativity?

### If yes:

[In this answer by **John Rennie**](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/215389), it is stated that:

> **Lorentzian manifolds are a special case of pseudo-Riemannian manifolds where the signature of the metric is (3,1) (or (1,3) depending on your sign convention).**

Since Lorentzian manifolds ≡ signature (1,3), if the answer to my question is yes, it means that the General relativity spacetime is a 4D Lorentzian manifold.

Comment: Do you have any particular reason to think that the answer is "no"?

Comment: Yes i do, because [in this comment by Valter Moretti](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/92271) he suggests to look for Pseudo-riemannian manifolds instead of Lorentzian manifolds when in **General relativity**; and concerning the question "Is the Schwarzschild metric a metric of Lorentzian manifold",  he replies with "It is a metric of Pseudo-riemannian manifolds"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. In GR, spacetime is a 4D Lorentzian manifold